# Unable to install any package through pip

Tags: python, pip

For some reason I have issues installing new packages with my pip. I have an OS Sierra environment and everything was working fine before. Now either I use a virtualenv or not, I get:

```
Collecting requests
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests (from 
  versions: )
No matching distribution found for requests
```

This is not only for the "requests" library but also for all the others (e.g. django etc.).

I have the latest pip:

```
 pip --version
 returns: pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
```

And my python version is: 2.7.12

Moreover based [on this article](https://bhch.github.io/posts/2017/04/fix-the-pip-error-couldnt-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement/) I checked if I can curl the PyPi website and I do get a response back.

Any idea what is wrong?

**EDITED**

I executed the pip install as:

```
pip install -vvv requests
```

and I get a detailed output of the error:

```
Collecting requests
  2 location(s) to search for versions of requests:
  * http://pypi.python.org/simple/requests/
  * http://pypi.wfp.org/simple/requests/
  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/requests/
  Starting new HTTP connection (1): pypi.python.org
  "GET /simple/requests/ HTTP/1.1" 403 16
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/requests/: 403 Client 
  Error: SSL is required for url: http://pypi.python.org/simple/requests/ - 
  skipping
  Getting page http://pypi.wfp.org/simple/requests/
  Starting new HTTP connection (1): pypi.wfp.org
  "GET /simple/requests/ HTTP/1.1" 404 None
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.wfp.org/simple/requests/: 404 Client 
  Error: NOT FOUND for url: http://pypi.wfp.org/simple/requests/ - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests (from 
  versions: )
 Cleaning up...
  No matching distribution found for requests
 Exception information:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-
py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
  status = self.run(options, args)
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-
py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 324, in run
requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-
py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-
py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
require_hashes
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-
py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", 
line 514, in find_requirement
'No matching distribution found for %s' % req
DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for requests
```

Comment: On the `requests` doc website, it is written: "The use of Python 3 is highly preferred over Python 2. Consider upgrading your applications and infrastructure if you find yourself still using Python 2 in production today. If you are using Python 3, congratulations — you are indeed a person of excellent taste. —Kenneth Reitz".

Comment: How did you run `pip`?

Comment: @vinzee That *opinion* does not mean `requests` is incompatible with Python 2.7.

Comment: @Klaus D. I executed as always: pip install requests

Comment: Try `pip -v install requests`!

Comment: @Klaus D. please see edited question

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your HTTP. Are you using a proxy? Can you open the URLs shown (e.g. `http://pypi.python.org/simple/requests/`) in the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Klaus D. comment (proposed to add: the -v flag in the command), I found out that the URL for:

```
  http://pypi.python.org/simple/requests/
```

needs to be changed to

```
  https://pypi.python.org/simple/requests/  (with SSL).
```

Executing this command worked fine:

```
pip install -v requests -i https://pypi.python.org/simple/
```

Alternatively you can change the pip.conf file as described in one of the answers [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4817):

```
[global]
timeout = 60
index-url = https://pypi.python.org/simple
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution proposed by user1919 helped me to resolve installation of tox on lxc ubuntu container as the defualt pip version 8 doesn't recognize the correct url

I used:

```
pip install -v tox -i https://pypi.python.org/simple/
....
....
....
Successfully installed filelock-3.0.10 pluggy-0.9.0 py-1.8.0 setuptools-40.8.0 toml-0.10.0 tox-3.7.0 virtualenv-16.4.3
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth trying
`pip install --ignore-installed --no-cache-dir pip` to get an uncorrupted pip version (see [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4823) for the full issue).