# Getting error while installing any package in python : HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url

Tags: python, pip

I am installing Flask on my ubuntu system, but unable to install it. Getting the following error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 795, in get_page
    resp.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/models.py", line 935, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/flask/
```

I tried some solution from **Stackoverflow** but nothing works for me

[Unable to install any package through pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48109956/unable-to-install-any-package-through-pip/48110633)

I'm using `ubuntu 18.04`, `Python 2.7`, `pip 9.0.1`

Comment: You are installing 'flusk' ?? Or is it 'flask' ??

Comment: Sorry corrected the question I'm installing `flask`, even `request` and other basics module are through the same error

Comment: Did you try upgrading pip ? Any way this question must be moved to askubuntu.com ?

Comment: Do you mean python and pip version it creating issues here?

Comment: 'pip install Flask' must do the job. I hope the same command you are trying

Comment: @Kris Yes I'm trying the same

Comment: are you installing on virtualenv? or system

Comment: I'm installing it on my own System

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ pip install --upgrade pip
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/54/eb/4a3642e971f404d69d4f6fa3885559d67562801b99d7592487f1ecc4e017/pip-20.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 9.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-9.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-9.0.1
Successfully installed pip-20.3.3
```

Fixed the problem for me.