# Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: 404 Client Error

Tags: python, pip

[image: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: 404 Client Error:]

How to resolve the above error?

Comment: First check for internet connection and also please go through this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48109956/unable-to-install-any-package-through-pip

Comment: The current syntax for installing packages  from the given requirements file  is `pip install -r <path of your requirements.txt file>` .

Comment: Answers have already been provided by members. This page has an explanation for the syntax .. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180713/pip-install-requirements-txt-command-returns-many-errors-including-404-not-fo .

Comment: Please add your text as text and not as an image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing -r command flag, so go again with

```
 pip install -r requirements.txt
```

As it was before, `pip` just tries to get `requirements.txt` from remote store expecting it to be a package name.

See `pip help install`

**Usage:**

```
pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options]...
pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options]...

...

pip also supports installing from "requirements files", which 
provide an easy way to specify a whole environment to be installed.
```

**Install Options:**

```
-r, --requirement <file>    Install from the given requirements file. 
                            This option can be used multiple times.
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is `pip install -r requirements.txt`

```
Install Options:
  -r, --requirement <file>    Install from the given requirements file. This option can be used multiple times.
```