# Virtualenv stopped working due to failed download

Tags: python, virtualenv

I tried to run `virtualenv` today and it has stopped working. It was working ok just a couple of days ago and I haven't changed anything since. I'm on debian 10 - I updated all debian packages with `apt-get update` then `apt-get upgrade` just to make sure that wasn't the cause, but it didn't fix the issue. From the below output errors it looks like `virtualenv` does a network call to https://pypi.org/simple/pkg-resources/ which does not exist. I'm actually quite surprised `virtualenv` goes off to download packages when run. Maybe its because something is out of date?

**How can I get virtualenv working again?**

Please let me know if you need more information to help me fix this and I will happily provide updates.

```
$ virtualenv .
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2
New python executable in /home/me/myproject/bin/python2
Not overwriting existing python script /home/me/myproject/bin/python (you must use /home/me/myproject/bin/python2)
Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command /home/me/myproject/bin/python2 - setuptools pkg_resources pip wheel:
  Looking in links: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, /usr/share/python-wheels/
Collecting setuptools
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e1/b7/182161210a13158cd3ccc41ee19aadef54496b74f2817cc147006ec932b4/setuptools-44.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pkg_resources
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/pkg-resources/

----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2379, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 724, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 996, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 926, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 817, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /home/me/myproject/bin/python2 - setuptools pkg_resources pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

Note that I get the above output even after installing `virtualenv` again (without removing it first). Here is the output from the installation:

```
$ pip install virtualenv
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /home/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (20.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata>=0.12; python_version < "3.8" in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from virtualenv) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs<2,>=1.4.3 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from virtualenv) (1.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.1 in /home/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from virtualenv) (0.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-resources>=1.0; python_version < "3.7" in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from virtualenv) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from virtualenv) (3.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: six<2,>=1.9.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from virtualenv) (1.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pathlib2<3,>=2.3.3; python_version < "3.4" and sys_platform != "win32" in /home/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from virtualenv) (2.3.5)
Requirement already satisfied: contextlib2; python_version < "3" in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from importlib-metadata>=0.12; python_version < "3.8"->virtualenv) (0.6.0.post1)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from importlib-metadata>=0.12; python_version < "3.8"->virtualenv) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: configparser>=3.5; python_version < "3" in /home/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from importlib-metadata>=0.12; python_version < "3.8"->virtualenv) (3.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: singledispatch; python_version < "3.4" in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from importlib-resources>=1.0; python_version < "3.7"->virtualenv) (3.4.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: typing; python_version < "3.5" in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from importlib-resources>=1.0; python_version < "3.7"->virtualenv) (3.7.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scandir; python_version < "3.5" in /home/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pathlib2<3,>=2.3.3; python_version < "3.4" and sys_platform != "win32"->virtualenv) (1.10.0)
```

Comment: have you to reinstall it, you know type again `pip install virtualenv`

Comment: @Aditya yes I tried that too. I will post the output in case it gives any clues

Comment: you need to change the interpreter, virtualenv is using python 2  and your virtualenv require/defined in python3

Comment: It's not the same question, but it's the same issue here - you may want to have a look at the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48109956/unable-to-install-any-package-through-pip/48110633

Comment: @sahasrara62 I did notice that too. But the thing is, it was working like this just fine 2 days ago - hence why I suspect the URL is to blame. But anyway, I don't mind trying your suggestion. I need to use python2 for my application. How should I do this?

Comment: maybe as you updated the system it changed, instead of using  `pip install virtualenv`, do use `python2 -m pip install virtualenv` and run create virtualenv with python2 pip not with python3 using `python2 -m virtualenv <rest of coomand>` and then activate that environment and then run project/install dependencies

Comment: @Grismar afaik that is a different issue with http vs https. my url has https, but the actual link to the pypi website is broken. maybe its because python2 is deprecated as of jan 2021 so pypi.org has started removing packages...

Answer (score 1):

Try running pip this way:

```sh
$ python2 -m ensurepip --upgrade && python2 -m pip install --no-cache virtualenv
```

Potential cause: you've [updated to Debian 11](https://wiki.debian.org/Python)?

> Python, the high-level, interactive object oriented language, includes an extensive class library with lots of goodies for network programming, system administration, sounds and graphics. Debian provides the latest stable Python 3 release; it also provides the latest stable Python 2 release, but Python 2 is unsupported by the Python Foundation since 2020-01-01 and is being removed as of Debian 11 (Bullseye). It may also provide additional versions, as well as tons of third party packages. Python is an important part of the Debian ecosystem.

Comment: should that be `python2 -m ensurepip`?